# MPICH 1.XX version needed for cluster computing

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cluster-computing

Where can i find ?

> MPICH 1.xx

version software for Ubuntu on Internet.i can only find MPICH2 and MPICH3.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/

I found this on the main MPICH downloads page, right where is says, "Older releases are available [here](http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/)."  The archive goes back to version 0.9.1.